# Knockout.js $index as name

Tags: knockout.js

How can i use the $index to be the name of an element giving the following example:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" />
<input type="text" name="name2" />
<input type="text" name="name3" />
```

Comment: What have you tried? $index is a function so be sure to use it as such. `$index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr: { name: 'name' + $index() }">
```